# Protection against data leak from a usb drive plugged in a virtual machine?

Tags: usb-drive, dlp

Some peoples working with virtual machines need to plug USB drive on their computer or VM, in order to work (flash OS, put firmwares, upload configurations).

There is no data leak policy or software running in the VM as they grab the image from internet.

- How can I prevent them to exfiltrate confidential data from their main OS to the USB stick by using the virtual machine?
- Can the policy and software on the system, catch the data leak between the VM and USB or the only opportunity is from the main OS to the virtual machine?

Comment: Let's see if I understand you correctly: you want users to a) run arbitrary VM downloaded from untrusted sources and b) allow these VM to access the file system of the main OS (because otherwise they could not leak data from the main OS from inside the VM). In this case I wonder why you focus on data leaks by USB only and not for example leaking data from using the network connectivity of the VM or even ransomware in the VM compromising data on the main OS.

Comment: For the network connectivity perspective, I guess the network DLP would protect the main OS and the VM data exfiltration (unless the VM can connect independently to another untrusted network).
For the ransomware you are right, maybe I could host the trusted .iso in an internal server and block the download website.

Comment: I think by focusing your question on data leak by USB only you tackle the problem from the wrong end and also ignore several attacks. Instead you should limit what data the VM can see from the main OS in the first place, since what is not visible in the VM cannot be leaked from there no matter which method. Unfortunately it is not clear what the actual requirements here in your use case, i.e. if any data exchanged between VM and main OS is needed at all or if the VM even needs access to all data on the main OS.